# How can I post-process generated strings?

Tags: .net, autofixture

I want to customise AutoFixture's generation of strings so that the resulting string contains only letters. I only need this to apply if I explicitly ask AutoFixture for a `string`; I don't need this to apply to properties or anything else indirect. I intend to do this by transforming the strings generated by AutoFixture.

So given that I have some way of doing this transformation:

```
string ConvertToLettersOnly(string text);
```

How can I tell AutoFixture to post-process all generated strings through this method?

I've tried the following two approaches, but they seem to cause infinite recursion:

1.

```
Fixture.Customize<string>(c => c.FromFactory<string>(ConvertToLettersOnly));
```

2.

```
class LettersOnlySpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var type = request as Type;
        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            var text = (string)context.Resolve(request);
            return ConvertToLettersOnly(text);
        }

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only need it when you *explicitly* request a `string`, then why don't you just go `var s = ConvertToLettersOnly(fixture.Create<string>());`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Or `fixture.Get(ConvertToLettersOnly)` if your language allows :P

Comment: @RubenBartelink Wow, I had forgotten about the `Get` overloads - and I was the one who wrote them :o

Comment: @MarkSeemann And with real type inference you can easily get carried away sprinkling `sut.Method |> fixture.Do` and `let result = sut.Calculate |> fixture.Get` about (as you may or may not be aware F#, if you declare a Fact param without a type and pass it to a Method in the body of the fact, adding a new param to `Method` silently makes the param become a Tuple of the two args so there's no difference in resilience AFAICT. All part of the master plan I assume :D

Answer (score 2):

Look at `Generator<T>` as applied in [Mark's excellent implementation of the String calculator kata](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/02/06/StringCalculatorkatawithAutoFixture/) using AutoFixture.

If that isn't appropriate, you may wish to use an impl approach like that in [`ConstrainedStringGenerator`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/ConstrainedStringGenerator.cs) as [discussed here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/11/07/Creatinglength-constrainedstringswithAutoFixture/).

Applying that as a `Customize` could be done like so:

```
fixture.Customize( (Generator<char> generator) => 
{
    var filteredGenerator =
        from specimen in generator
        where TODOILike( specimen)
        select specimen;
    return String.Concat( filteredGenerator.Take( TODOLengthILike));
});
```